# Export stack of plots in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a stack of plots which are actually individual charts and would like to override the behaviour of the export options which appear on the first chart to save them all?

Could that be possible? I have the charts in an array in my javascript.

[image]

One also annoying feature, is that menu is truncated. Is there a way to bring this to the front? I didn't see an option.

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't it just grab the png image of the current canvas? If each chart is on its own canvas (layer), then go through them and export each layer.

Comment: But how do you capture the click event from the menu?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to create one chart with multiple `yAxis`:

```
series: [{
    data: [...]
}, {
    data: [...],
    yAxis: 1
}, {
    data: [...],
    yAxis: 2
}],
yAxis: [{
    height: '30%'
}, {
    height: '30%',
    offset: 0,
    top: '33%'
}, {
    height: '30%',
    offset: 0,
    top: '66%'
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rha36dfz/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis

Comment: Unfortunately they need to be individual charts as they can be removed and updated individually. Is it possible to catch one of the events for example?

Comment: Hi @user1472672, Please check this thread: https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=40382 Please do not hesitate to ask if you have any futher questions.

Comment: Thanks @ppotaczek - Is it possible to do this using the existing exporting context menu that highcharts provides rather than adding an individual button? Somehow to catch say the click event each of the menu options then apply the code in the thread you mentioned? Also is there a way to bring the export menu to the front, so it isn't covered as per the screenshot? Thanks greatly

Comment: Hi @user1472672, You can add some custom buttons with functions to the export menu. To show full menu, you need to set `overflow` to `visible` and change the elements order. Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rkd5a6wp/